# Flutter Riverpod - Initialize with async values

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-provider, riverpod

I'm trying to learn Riverpod and I have a `ChangeNotifierProvider` that has a few fields that need to be initialized with a value that is returned from an async operation. Is this possible, as I know I cant create the `ChangeNotifierProvider` asynchronously?

Example `ChangeNotifierProvider`

```
class SomeState extends ChangeNotifier {
  String email = '';

  // needs to be set to value returned from
  // shared preferences upon init
}
```

If not possible, is there another provider that could work better knowing I want to initialize its value to the returned value from async method?

Comment: Forcing the state to wait for the returned value of a future can stall the whole app. Instead, call the async method within the initialization of your state and, when it is complete, save the value and call `notifyListeners()` to rebuild any listening widgets.

Comment: Thanks @Abion47, that makes sense. Going to try to refactor.

Comment: You can add a "bool isLoading" flag

Comment: Thanks @RémiRousselet, not sure I follow where I should put this flag though?

Comment: Inside your `SomeState` class

Comment: something like `class SomeState extends ChangeNotifier {
  String email = '';
  bool isLoading = false;

  void init() async {
      isLoading = true;
      var res = await method();
      email = res.email;
      isLoading = false;
      notifylListeners();
  }
}`  ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is possible as Abion47's comment. Let me show more details in the code below

```dart
class EmailNotifier extends ChangeNotifier {
  String email = '';

  void load() {
    functionReturnFuture.then(value) {
      setEmail(value);
    }
  }

  void setEmail(String value) {
    // email loaded but not changed, so no need to notify the listeners
    if(value == email) return;

    // email has loaded and change then we notify listeners
    email = value;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}


var emailNotifier = ChangeNotifierProvider<EmailNotifier>((ref) {
  var notifier = EmailNotifier();

  // load the email asynchronously, once it is loaded then the EmailNotifier will trigger the UI update with notifyListeners
  notifier.load();
  return notifier;
});
```

As we manage state independently from Flutter UI, there is nothing blocking you from running code to trigger a state change, for example in our case **notifier.load()**.

After **notifier.load()** and email is set then the provider will trigger UI change using **notifyListeners()**.

You can achieve a similar result using FutureProvider.

Comment: To add to this, you can use AsyncValue here to make it act like the mutable equivalent of AsyncStateNotifier — using AsyncValue<String> for the state instead of just String.